# Drupal 7 Messages only show after class registry clear

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Need to show some messages from hook_block_view.

so in the function setting a message like:

```
drupal_set_message('Block should have loaded');
```

Does not work.
If I clear class registry, it works once, then every other time it does not show.
It looks like drupal is redirecting or something before the page is rendered. Using `drupal_exit();` by the end of this function does show everything is correct so far, but does not make it to the final output.

Edit:
It works if I throw in `drupal_flush_all_caches` But then goes super slow obviously. Seems to be some sort of caching problem.

Comment: `hook_block_view` is a hook executed before a lot of functions , why do you need to display this message into your block view ? what is your final purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off full caching for the block under [hook_block_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_block_info/7) by setting 'cache' to: DRUPAL_NO_CACHE

```
function hook_block_info() {

    $blocks = array();

    $blocks['abc'] = array(
      'info' => t('test block'),
      'visibility' => 0,
      'status' => TRUE,
      'region' => 'none',
      'weight' => 99,
      'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
   );

   return $blocks;
}
```

Then try to write

```
drupal_set_message('Block should have loaded');
```

within hook_block_view and check now...

it may be help for you.

Comment: Yes it was originally set to cache per user. Thanks!